# Owl Carousel center two items

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I'm trying to use Owl carousel 2 to create a slider which centers two items instead of the option which centers one. So far I've managed to add an extra class to the item left of the centered item by adding some lines to the source code.

```
if (this.settings.center) {
    this.$stage.children('.center').removeClass('center');
    this.$stage.children().eq(this.current()).addClass('center');
    this.$stage.children('.next-to-center').removeClass('next-to-center');
    this.$stage.children().eq(this.current() - 1).addClass('next-to-center');
}
```

But I can't figure out howto make two items centered when I show four items. I want to clip each item on the side of the centered items in half. Anyone know how I can do this, or have a recommendation of a library that includes this?

Here is a fiddle with an example on how long I've come so far

http://jsfiddle.net/7e97o5hn/4/